# How to create a navbar in react material-ui-next

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to go through the documentation but I can't find an efficient solution for navbar? Is there any best practices for creating a navbar in material-ui-next?

Comment: What are  the requirements? What did you do achieve so far? Maybe [drawers](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/drawers/) fit your needs